# When are you a high rep user?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Might be a silly question, but I'm wondering, when do you consider a user a high rep user? Has the user to be in the top 10?/50? or does he need 10000+ rep, etc.

Just being curious...

Comment: If you're above me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not really a defined "greater than X reputation = high rep user."  If a username is in the top one or two pages of SU users, then they are usually higher reputation users.

It is also relative to each site and the time it has been active.  SO for example has 17k rep users on page 10 of the Users rankings. There are only 4 users currently that have > 17k rep on SU for comparison.

EDIT:

I like what DMA57361 was mentioning there in his second point.  Any user that uses the new abilities given to them at certain rep levels and uses them to advance and improve the site would be ideal.  Super User can always use more people to help edit and improve questions throughout the site.  Of course, we need great answers also.

Comment: Top *2* pages? I've only another ½ page to climb then - Hurrah! :D

Comment: @DMA57361 Haha! Go you!

Answer (score 10):

[image: The question owner (didn't really) accept this answer as the best at some point]

I'd like to add one more criterion to the conversation, so that a "high rep" user is anyone who:

1. Meets some expected rep score / percentile / ranking / etc.
2. Makes use of **all** their "powers", and does so correctly.
   (ie, doesn't just use the basic "low-level" "powers", but *actively* acts as a high rep user).

Comment: I wish I could mark two as accepted!

Comment: @BloodPhilia - that's OK, I've made myself a tick so I don't feel left out.

Comment: @DMA  OK, you almost made me believe I found a bug when I saw the extra accepted answer check mark in your post.  Good one. :)

Comment: @Troggy: same here. I'm thinking, "WTF, why are there two accepted answers and WHY is that checkmark over there??!?!?!"

Comment: Nice. Sorry about that... next time, to help make it obvious, I'll make the tick bigger! or freehand! or orange! or *all three*!

Comment: Hahaha! That made me laugh...